# Error with rosmake bumblebee2 (fuerte)

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, rosmake, bumblebee, bumblebee2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS, so I got stuck at this step of installing the bumblebee2 package.
I solved a prior dependency issue with libdc1394v2, however my error when make is trying to compile bumblebee2.cpp, the following error occurs:

```
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bumblebee2.dir/src/bumblebee2.o
/home/juan/ros_workspace/bumblebee2/src/bumblebee2.cpp:55:45: fatal error:  
camera_info_manager/camera_info.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm thinking that it could be some some sort of package dependency issue, but I'm not sure how I would fix this, or where the header file is that it's looking for.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33666/error-with-rosmake-bumblebee2-(fuerte)/) by [Juan.Guzman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2352/juan.guzman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This question](http://answers.ros.org/question/11546/libdc1394-package-not-available-for-diamondback) may be similar to yours.

You seem to be using a very old camera driver, not actively maintained.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using the bumblebee package available on the ROS webiste and not the cornell version, then following will work:

1. Change camera_info.h to camera_info_manager.h
2. Replace the places where the variable cinfo_ is declared/initialized to camera_info_manager::cinfo_h
3. Follow the updates mentioned [here.](http://www.roschina.net/ros/www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte(2f)Migration.html)

The package installed successfully for me. It runs - but no data is posted at runtime!

---

Originally posted by [Pulkit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2984/pulkit/) with karma: 11 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1